# Extract text() and get attributes from it

Tags: python, html, regex, xpath, lxml.html

I get an html tag with xpath, with conditions, and now i get the value with text(). Is there any way to get attributes from this value? (text())

Value from text()

```
document.write("<a href="http://www...">hello</a>");
```

Now i'll get the whole line (thats ok so far). And now i want so get the /@href from that value.

Here my code:

```
code = "...<script>document.write("<a href="http://www...">hello</a>"); </script>..."

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(code)
value = doc.xpath( "//script[contains(text(), 'document.write') and (contains(text(),'href'))]//text()" )
```

I can try it with regex, but maybe there is another good way to fix my problem with xpath.

Thanks

Comment: Is that your actual code? `document.write("<a href="http://www...">hello</a>");` looks like a syntax error to me.

Comment: Nope, i cut off some not relevant parts

Comment: I'm not referring to the "..." in your url, if that's what you mean. I'm referring to your use of double quotes inside a double quoted string, which is illegal syntax. Look at your code samples in this question. See how most of the lines are red? That's because the code formatting tool thinks that they're string literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using `regex` by calling `LH.fromstring` on the text inside the `<script>` tag:

```
import lxml.html as LH
code = '...<script>document.write("<a href="http://www...">hello</a>"); </script>...'

doc = LH.fromstring(code)
for text in doc.xpath( "//script[contains(text(), 'document.write') and (contains(text(),'href'))]//text()" ):
    script = LH.fromstring(text)
    print(script.xpath('//a/@href'))
```

yields

```
['http://www...']
```

Comment: Cool, look like the solution i want. In the next step, i must extract <scr'+'ipt> within the document.write function. Problem: <scr'+'ipt> is not a valid tag that i extract like the <a> tag. Any idea how i can do this with the same method / way?

Comment: Someone with more knowledge of JavaScript than I have may be able to show you how to handle this more robustly. From the Python side, all I can suggest is using regex or `str.replace` to convert `"<scr'+'ipt>"` to `<script>`.

Answer (score -1):

We have to follow following steps to get `href` value of "a" tag from "script" tags:

1. Get text of the "script" tags by `getiterator` method.
2. Again create script_root for the text of "script" tag.
3. Find `href` attribute of the "a" tag by `getiterator` method.

>

```
code = """"<script>document.write("<a href="http://www...">hello</a>"); </script>"""
from lxml import html
root = html.fromstring(code)
for i in root.getiterator("script"):
    script_root = html.fromstring(i.text)
    for j in script_root.getiterator("a"):
        try:print "href:-", j.attrib["href"]
        except:pass
```

Comment: Posting code is not enough - please also explain what it does. Thanks!

Comment: @MathiasMüller: yes, explanation was missing, now added explanation.